# TextView fade out and disappear

Tags: android, animation, textview

I have a `TextView` in my activity, I would like to show the text, then fade out and hide it completely whenever the activity is started.

I have a wired situation, my code sometimes working (the `TextView` is fade out and gone), but most of times, it is not working (it could not reach the `onAnimationEnd` function).

Here is my code for it:

```
protected void onResume() {
    fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation( 1.0f , 0.0f ) ;
    fadeOut.setDuration(5000);
    //fadeOut.setFillBefore(true);
    fadeOut.setFillAfter(true);
    //fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);


    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "fade out start");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "fade out end");

            textRotateHint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "fade out repeat");
        }
    });

    textRotateHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textRotateHint.setText(R.string.rotation_hint);
    textRotateHint.startAnimation(fadeOut);

    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: This could mean `onResume()` is not always called.

Comment: for my debugging, I can see the it reached: Log.d(TAG, "fade out start"); but never goes to: Log.d(TAG, "fade out end");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple value animator.

```
ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f, 0f);
valueAnimator.setDuration(5000);
valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float alpha = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        mTextView.setAlpha(alpha);
    }
});
valueAnimator.start();
```